# How to create a JSONArray that contains Javascript code inside Java?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am creating a JSONArray and parse it to a String, but as it even contains Strings instead of code it doesn't output as I need it.

```
for(Place place: places){
    locations.put("new google.maps.LatLng("+place.getContactData().getLatitude()+","+place.getContactData().getLongitude()+")");
}
return locations.toString();
```

It outputs as: `["new google.maps.LatLng(53.5608,9.96357)","new google.maps.LatLng(53.5608,9.96357)"]` but I need it without quotation marks like `[new google.maps.LatLng(53.5608,9.96357),new google.maps.LatLng(53.5608,9.96357)]` to be correctly interpreted by javascript.

Comment: And `[new google.maps.LatLng(53.5608,9.96357),new google.maps.LatLng(53.5608,9.96357)]` is going to be a string inside JSON itself or not? Because if not, then it's invalid JSON.

Comment: There is no code in a JSON data structure, thats simply not supported by the format.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be:

create an array with just the coordinates:

```
for(Place place: places){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("lat",place.getContactData().getLatitude());
    obj.put("lng",place.getContactData().getLongitude());
    locations.put(obj);
}
```

and then in javascript:

```
var places = (yourPlacesJson);
var placeObjects = [];

for(var i=0;i<places.length;i++)
{
    placeObjects[placeObjects.length] = new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat,places[i].lng);
}
```

Comment: Sounds really smart. In the source code the array shows up as `var places = [{"lng":9.963569641113281,"lat":53.56079864501953},{"lng":9.979949951171875,"lat":53.55149841308594}];` but when I `alert(places)` it is empty. What might I have missed?

Comment: @Lester: There is not enough information to answer this question. Maybe you call `alert(places)` where `places` is not visible. Note that if you get the output `[object Object],[object Object]`, that's perfectly normal.

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Maybe just some browser cache issue. :)
Thanks a lot for all replies!

Answer (score 1):

JSON only supports plain-old-data. It can't include any executable code (a `new` is executable code). This is by design - when JSON would be able to include executable code you would have to be much more carefully with importing JSON from an untrusted source.

All you can do is pass javascript code as strings and `eval()` it on the JS side after parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use Regular expressions to remove the ", if you parse the json to another language

Answer (score -1):

i had a similar problem, the way i made this work:

instead of writing the javascript before the json conversion, insert a placeholder.

```
locations.put("%mapsPlaceholder1%");
```

then after filling the array with placeholders, do:

```
locations.toString().replaceFirst("\"%mapsPlaceholder1%\"","yourJsCode");
```

something like that

you could also just create the array string manually

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice approach. I just can't think of a way to do this for the whole List `places`.

Comment: i think an actually better way for your problem would be:
just add the coordinates to the array, and then create the google.maps.LatLng object in javascript by iterating through the array

Comment: sounds like a fine plan b. Thank you!

Comment: look my 2nd answer, thats how i would do it